# Printing to the console with NUnit Engine

Tags: console, nunit, nunit-3.0

How can I print to the NUnit console when using NUnit engine?  I have already tried using Console.Write, TestContext.Write, and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine but none of them will output anything to the console; as of right now, the NUnit console has no output at all.  I need a solution where I can print to the console in both the project when NUnit engine is running as well as in the tests themselves.  What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: It should work. Please post the command-line you are using and add the version numbers of both the nunit.framework.dll and the nunit3-console.exe you are using.

Comment: I couldn't get it.  I wound up just redirecting the console output to a text box within my windows form.  That being said, is there a way I can hide the NUnit window now?

Comment: It sounds like you are running nunit programmatically and not from the console command-line. I guess that's what you meant by "using NUnit engine."

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running NUnit tests from a program, by calling the engine, no output is produced. If you think about it, programs that use a library don't normally want that library to produce output without being told to do so.

In this case, all output from your tests are sent back to you in the form of events. All normal writes (Console.Write, TestContext.Write) come to you bundled in the test result. Immediate writes (Console.Error, TestContext.Error, TestContext.Progress) come in the form of testoutput events. It's up to you to do what you want with them.

Both the NUnit console runner and the gui have to do this, so you can check the code for some ideas about how to handle the events.

Comment: Can you give me some direction on where the gui is doing this?  I'm looking through the code now but I hardly even know where to start.

Comment: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-gui/blob/master/src/nunit-gui/Presenters/TestPropertiesPresenter.cs#L134

Comment: Note that the current (0.3) version of the gui does not display immediate output.

Comment: That would print the output after the tests are run, correct?  I need to print to the console continuously, like I could in previous versions of NUnit.  For example, I want my SetUp method to print "[Start Test]" and I want my TearDown method to print "[Complete Test]".  Is it possible to do that with NUnit 3?

Comment: NUnit sends "normal" output as __each__ test completes. It sends immediate output... immediately. Immediate output is produced using Console.Error, TestContext.Error or TestContext.Progress. It's up to the program that's running the test to handle those immediate output events just as the console runner does.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not running it correctly then.  Currently, the runner runs in one line (runner.Run()).  How would I capture the results while it's running in that case?

Comment: Where are you getting your "runner" from? "Run()" without args is not part of the ITestRunner interface. See https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitEngine/nunit.engine.api/ITestRunner.cs#L78

Comment: ITestRunner runner = engine.GetRunner(package);
runner.Run(null, TestFilter.Empty);

package being a TestPackage with the assembly path and working directory setting.

Comment: You are passing in a null for the test event listener. Essentially, you are telling the runner to throw away all events, including all output from the test. The test event listener __is__ what should be displaying the tests. By running NUnit programmatically, you have the responsibility to decide what gets displayed, where and how.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?  The only thing I could find was a spec sheet but that wasn't very helpful for getting set up.  I'm not sure what I'm supposed to tell the runner what to do.

Comment: As a programmer using NUnit, your primary documentation is the interface definition and the code itself. You merely need to implement the interface and handle those events you want to handle. See https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Result-XML-Format for documentation of the test-result event, which includes the normal output. For immediate output, you need to capture the `<test-output>` event. I see we haven't documented it, but I think you'll find the content fairly obvious once you see it in the debugger.

Comment: Just to be clear... NUnit doesn't require you to do anything with these events, or even to capture them. But if you want any info to display on the console, you will have to display it yourself. The engine is a back-end component and doesn't have a console available to it.